# Bind Variable is not declared

Tags: sql, oracle

Привет . 
Учусь работать с Index-by tables .

```
DECLARE  
  TYPE population_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(64);
  country_population population_type;
  howmany NUMBER;
  status NUMBER;
BEGIN
  country_population('Greenland') := 100000; -- Creates new entry
  country_population('MILAN') := 3000;
  howmany := country_population('Greenland');
  status := country_population('MILAN');
  END;
  /
```

Создал массив данных и передаю их пеерменным . 
Получаю ошибку

> Bind Variable "howmany" is not declared.

при вызове кода :

```
 SELECT :howmany from dual;
```

Как передать значение в переменную и получить ее ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут у Вас перепутаны [переменные pl/sql](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/01_oview.htm#708) и [переменные Sql*Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1014308).

Сначала Вы объявляете переменную **howmany** как переменную pl/sql а потом пытаетесь использовать ее как переменную Sql*Plus.

Чтобы ее можно было так использовать нужно объявить ее иначе:

```
variable howmany number;

DECLARE  
  TYPE population_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(64);
  country_population population_type;
  status NUMBER;
BEGIN
  country_population('Greenland') := 100000; -- Creates new entry
  country_population('MILAN') := 3000;
  :howmany := country_population('Greenland');
  status := country_population('MILAN');
END;
/

select :howmany from dual
/
```